# Show $B_\infty(0,1)$ is not open for $\|.\|_1$ in $C^0(0,1)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $C^0(0,1)$ the set of continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

We equip this space with either the norm $\|.\|_1$ or $\|.\|_\infty$

We note $B_\infty(0,1)$ the unit ball for $\|.\|_\infty$ in $C^0$.

How to show that $B_\infty(0,1)$ is not open for $\|.\|_1$ in $C^0(0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f \equiv 0$ for instance, so $f\in B_{\infty}(0,1)$. If $B_{\infty}(0,1)$ were open wrt $\|\cdot\|_1$, there would be an $\epsilon >0$ such that for any $g\in C^0(0,1)$ such that
$$
\|g\|_1 < \epsilon \Rightarrow \|g\|_{\infty} < 1
$$
Now try to construct functions $g_n \in C^0(0,1)$ such that
$$
\|g_n\|_1 < 1/n \text{ but } \|g_n\|_{\infty} =2
$$

Comment: Thank you very much ! $g_n(x) := 2x^n$ makes it works.